# How do I create custom kafka consumer Interceptor to intercept one record at a time?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to add a custom consumer interceptor using `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerInterceptor`.

The problem I've here is the `onConsume()` method is taking `ConsumerRecords<String, Object>` records but i'm looking for intercepting only one record at a time instead of a bunch of records.

How do i do that? Please suggest

Comment: Are you trying to intercept and then process one at a time? Or would you just like an interface to calls .iterable().map and then has a new method that processes one at a time knowing that it's still processing them as a group?

Comment: set max.poll.records to 1. it doesn't affect fetching thou, your consumer thread will "take" a lot of messages and hold them for later poll calls. But calling `poll()` will return just one one (maybe what you need)

Comment: @Zergleb I'm trying to intercept one record at a time and add some custom stuff on that record

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve by implementing 'RecordInterceptor' interface from  'spring-kafka-2.7.7-RELEASE' without changing any settings on the kafka.

This new interface was added last week. You can see the details here if you are interested in.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1118

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring:
You can use
`org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor` with method
`public ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> intercept(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record)` this will work by intercepting one record at a time.
Then, if you're going to change record after sending you can use `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerInterceptor.

Answer (score 0):

As per the ConsumerInterceptor interface implementation, records will come in batch inside onConsume() method. You can iterate on this records and perform required business operation.